# Not able to start appium session

Tags: android, appium, nativeapplication

I am not able to start the session can you help. I have done the following steps:

1. Started a Appium server from Appium for windows package (ran appium.exe file)
2. Started a simulator for android
3. Started selenium server
4. Ran the script via TestNG

I am getting the following error when I enter the follwing in the browser

```
127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub:
That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource
```

My console shows the following error:

```
A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 306 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 7):

Try next:

> 127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/status

It should be valid url

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too many servers running with selenium. Try skipping step 3. Having 2 appium processes running will give you the same issue. I have seen it with running one on the command line and another from the executable.

So one instance of appium and one device attached (or emulator running) to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Appium responds with an error and then you start a new session. You need to call driver.quit() before you start a new session.