# "ERROR running Appium command: Cannot read property 'capabilities' of null"

Tags: python, appium

When trying to run a basic Hello World kind of test with Appium and python the following error happened:

WebDriverException: Message: That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource

Looking further I found that it happened when the web driver was initialized:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',          desired_caps)
```

So I typed in http://localhost:4723/wd/hub to the browser and got

> That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource

I googled, came across a QA here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973691/not-able-to-start-appium-session) but it doesn't solve it. I also typed in http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/status

```
{
    status: 0,
    value: {
        build: {
           version: "1.4.11",
           revision: "8cf8311f00e59a2b10fde1834fcf6d5ace6fbcd0"
        }
    }
}
```

And also wd/hub/session and got

```
{
   status: 13,
   value: "ERROR running Appium command: Cannot read property 'capabilities' of null"
}
```

Sadly there are only a few google results for any of these errors and those results don't help to solve the problem. So if you know how to make them go away, please help.

Comment: Solved it but not sure what exactly the solution is! Things I did include upgrading Node, juggling desired capabilities and reinstalling appium.

Comment: as usual with appium and appium related issues.. upgrade !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by launching Appium Inspector (magnifying glass icon) in Appium.app (on Mac).
[Appium issue.](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6059)