# That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource is observed, on executing java code for Appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

My before class code

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "28A4AA402080GI2");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Androdi");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.xxx.demo");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.sample.xxx.LoginActivity");
    wd = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/status"), capabilities);
    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

When

- http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/status is provided  error is That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP

  - http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub is provided error observed is A new session could not be created. (Original error: Permission to start activity denied.)

  Link: [Not able to start appium session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973691/not-able-to-start-appium-session)

i have gone through the above link before posting this Question. When i perform the steps suggested in the link, that works fine on browser. Where as the same from eclipse throws the error. So i feel this is not a duplicate..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to start appium session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973691/not-able-to-start-appium-session)

Comment: i have gone through the above link before posting this Question. When i perform the steps suggested in the link, that works fine on browser. Where as the same from eclipse throws the error. So i feel this is not a duplicate...

Comment: are you sure its the same port number that appium runs on, if yes, try changing the port no in appium servee as well as in your code and give it a shoot

Comment: Changed the port from 4723 to 4722 still same issue..

Comment: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Permission to start activity denied.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 7.11 seconds